# Required buffer for cuFFT

Tags: cuda, cufft

This question is about the buffer required by cuFFT. In the User Guide it is documented that

> In the worst case, the CUFFT Library allocates space for
>   8*batch*n[0]*..*n[rank-1] cufftComplex or cufftDoubleComplex elements
>   (where batch denotes the number of transforms that will be executed in
>   parallel, rank is the number of dimensions of the input data (see
>   Multidimensional transforms) and n[] is the array of transform
>   dimensions) for single and doubleprecision transforms respectively.

What does "array of transform dimensions" mean? How much buffer does cuFFT need? What I understand with the above is that it needs at least 8x the size of the array being FFTed but this does not make sense to me

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 3):

The "array of transform dimensions" is the array containing the problem size in each dimension, see the section on [multidimensional transforms](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#unique_1110380025) for more information.

cuFFT is allocating temporary space to be able to accommodate the intermediate data, the part of the doc you quoted says this is "the worst case", so it's not "at least 8x", it's at most. The doc [goes on](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#topic_2) to say:

> Depending on the configuration of the plan, less memory may be used.
>   In some specific cases, the temporary space allocations can be as low
>   as 1*batch*n[0]*..*n[rank-1] cufftComplex or cufftDoubleComplex
>   elements.

So for a NxM 2D single precision transform:

```
1*N*M*sizeof(cufftComplex) <= space for tmp data <= 8*N*M*sizeof(cufftComplex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cufftGetSize1d` and `cufftEstimate1d` to give you the amount of memory allocated for the buffer. The documentation says `cufftPlan1d` gives an estimation of the maximum amount and `cufftGetSize1d` provide a more precise estimation.

In my case I use both 64 and 8192 point FFTs. I get the same issue, the buffer size allocate only 1*batch*n[0] elements.I've made the test with different amount of data and different FFT size and I get this same value.

To conclude, if you need to determine the memory used by a FFT, the CuFFT library provide a fonction to do this.